# Setting Halo property of label using ArcPy and CIM

Tags: arcpy, labeling, arcgis-pro, cartographic-information-model

I don't know how to set halo property in Python. I try it by CIM (code below) but I don't know, what line "lc.textSymbol.symbol.haloSymbol" should contain.

Can you advise me how to achieve halo effect using ArcPy?

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map15")[0]

show_labels = m.listLayers("okolni_listy_ztm5*")[0]
show_labels.showLabels = True

for lyr in m.listLayers("okolni_listy_ztm5*"):
if lyr.supports("SHOWLABELS"):
if lyr.showLabels:
for lblClass in lyr.listLabelClasses():
lblClass.expression = "$feature.OBJECTID"

label_show = m.listLayers('okolni_listy_ztm5*')[0]
l_cim = label_show.getDefinition('V2')
lc = l_cim.labelClasses[0]


lc.textSymbol.symbol.haloSize = 2
lc.textSymbol.symbol.haloSymbol = 

label_show.setDefinition(l_cim)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code required to alter the Halo of a Text Symbol. I have to say it's not particularly clear from the help file how to do it and it took me some time to work it out. The [Python CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) page was useful.

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
myMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]

myLayer = myMap.listLayers("Home")[0]
myLayer.showLabels = True

# Create a colour
fillRGBColour = arcpy.cim.CreateCIMObjectFromClassName('CIMRGBColor', 'V2')
fillRGBColour.values = [170,255,0, 100] #light green

# Create a fill
solFill = arcpy.cim.CreateCIMObjectFromClassName('CIMSolidFill', 'V2')
solFill.color = fillRGBColour
solFill.enable = True
solFill.colorlocked = False
solFill.overprint = False

# Create a polygon symbol and set its symbol layers
sym = arcpy.cim.CreateCIMObjectFromClassName('CIMPolygonSymbol', 'V2')
sym.symbolLayers = [solFill] # Note fill object is in a list, an append() would not work

# Get CIM definition
l_cim = myLayer.getDefinition('V2')
lc = l_cim.labelClasses[0] # Returns first CIMLabelClass object

# Update halo properties of text symbol
lc.textSymbol.symbol.haloSize = 2
lc.textSymbol.symbol.haloSymbol = sym

# Update CIM defintion
myLayer.setDefinition(l_cim)
```